# Annualised Sharpe Ratio of a 24/7 Round-The-Clock High Frequency Trading Strategy

Tags: sharpe-ratio, bitcoin, ratio

Consider a high frequency trading strategy that trades Bitcoin-USD round the clock 365 days of the year at 5-minute intervals. How would one calculate the annualised Sharpe ratio of such a trading strategy?

Comment: your question depends on how many days your strategy has traded. 365 ?